# Quickbooks POS SDK weird btnHelp BeginSession error

Tags: c#, integration, quickbooks

I am trying to integrate a C# program with Quickbooks POS via Quickbooks POS SDK.  I have Quickbooks, Quickbooks SDK, Quickbooks POS and Quickbooks POS SDK installed.

When the following code hits "sessionManager.BeginSession("");" I get back error message "Error reading btnHelp.BorderColorSelected: Property BorderCo". Not a typo it ends with BorderCo.

Someone please help!

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using Interop.qbposfc3;

namespace POSTest2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void CustomerAdd()
        {                        
            QBPOSSessionManager sessionManager = new QBPOSSessionManager();

            IMsgSetRequest request = sessionManager.CreateMsgSetRequest(3, 0);
            request.Attributes.OnError = ENRqOnError.roeContinue;
            BuildItemInventoryAddRq(request);
            sessionManager.OpenConnection("appID", "Application");
            sessionManager.BeginSession("");
            IMsgSetResponse response = sessionManager.DoRequests(request);
            sessionManager.EndSession();
            sessionManager.CloseConnection();
        }

        private void BuildItemInventoryAddRq(IMsgSetRequest request)
        {
            IItemInventoryAdd ItemInventoryAddRq = request.AppendItemInventoryAddRq();
            ItemInventoryAddRq.ALU.SetValue("M9ine");
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CustomerAdd();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that you still need an answer,
but probably you need set up connection string in sessionManager.BeginSession() method:

```
string connectionString = "Computer Name=WORKPC;Company Data=YourQBCompany;Version=10";
sessionManager.BeginSession(connectionString)
```

Please see QB POS SDK dev guide, particularly using Begin Session method: http://dev.developer.intuit.com/POSSDK-Current/doc/pdf/QBPOS_ProgramGd.pdf

Answer (score 0):

also please make sure company file is in multi user mode.